# Webscraping (potentially) ill-formated HTML in R with xpath or regex

Tags: regex, r, xpath

I'm trying to extract the abstract from this [link](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_abstract&pid=S1981-38212013000100001&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en). However, I'm unable to extract only the content of the abstract. Here's what I accomplished so far:

```
url <- "http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_abstract&pid=S1981-38212013000100001&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en"
textList <- readLines(url)
text <- textList[grep("Abstract[^\\:]", textList)] # get the correct element
text1 <- gsub("\\b(.*?)\\bISSN", "" , text)
```

Up to this point I got almost what I want, but then I couldn't get rid of the rest of the string that isn't of interest to me.

I even tried another approach, with xpath, but unsuccessfully. I tried something like the code below, but to no effect whatsoever.

```
library(XML)
arg.xpath <-"//p/@xmlns"
doc <- htmlParse( url)   # parseia url
linksAux <- xpathSApply(doc, arg.xpath)
```

How can I accomplih what I want, either with regex or xpath, or maybe both?

ps.: my general aim is webscraping of several similar pages like the one I provided. I alredy can extract the link. I only need to get the abstract now. 
free(doc)

Comment: ```regexpr("<p xmlns=\"\">(.*?)</p>",text1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the XML approach because regular expressions with HTML can be quite a headache. I think your xpath expression was just a bit off. Try

```
doc <- htmlParse(url)
xpathSApply(doc, "//p[@xmlns]", xmlValue)
```

This returns (clipped for length)

```
[1] "HOLLANDA,  Cristina Buarque de. Human rights ..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[2] "This article is dedicated to recounting the main ..."
[3] "Keywords\n\t\t:\n\t\tHuman rights; transitional ..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[4] ""
```

Answer (score 1):

someone better could give you a better answer but this kinda works

```
reg=regexpr("<p xmlns=\"\">(.*?)</p>",text1)  
begin=reg[[1]]+12
end=attr(reg,which = "match.length")+begin-17
substr(text1,begin,end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, which is klunky as written, but offers the technique of keeping the right parts after splitting at tag tokens:

```
text2 <- sapply(strsplit(x = text1, ">"), "[", 3)
text2
[1] "This article is dedicated to recounting the main initiative of Nelson Mandela's government to manage the social resentment inherited from the segregationist regime. I conducted interviews with South African intellectuals committed to the theme of transitional justice and with key personalities who played a critical role in this process. The Truth and Reconciliation Commission is presented as the primary institutional mechanism envisioned for the delicate exercise of redefining social relations inherited from the apartheid regime in South Africa. Its founders declared grandiose political intentions to the detriment of localized more palpable objectives. Thus, there was a marked disparity between the ambitious mandate and the political discourse about the commission, and its actual achievements.</p"
text3 <- sapply(strsplit(text2, "<"), "[", 1)
```